# Coldfusion scheduler event Handler cannot be found

Tags: coldfusion, scheduler

Trying to add an Event handler to a scheduled task in ColdFusion11.
I'm supposed to write a component that implements CFIDE.scheduler.ITaskEventHandler and "Specify a dot-delimited CFC path under webroot, for example a.b.server (without the CFC extension)"

I tried to put my component under

- ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot
- ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/CFIDE
- ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/CFIDE/scheduler
- the Apache webroot
- some virtual host webroot

I tried to add some dot notation (?) like CFIDE.scheduler.myEventHandler...

I don't understand if there is some more configuration at server level to understand.
I don't see any error in logs, the scheduler editor just refuse to save an EventHandler he cannot find, with the error

An error occured scheduling the task.
Invalid eventhandler.
Error: Eventhandler myEventHandler could not be found

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The correct way seems to put the component in ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/myEventHandler.cfc, set the path as myEventHandler and implement in the component "CFIDE.scheduler.ITaskEventHandler"